# How does the system identify an executable file

Tags: operating-systems

How does the system identify an executable file from a data file or a media file...is the system just looking for known extensions or is there something more low level that determines whether its executable...just to know out of curiosity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Windows: It just look file extension. Any .exe file extension will be treated as an executable.
- Linux: It is a user choice. any file can be whathever the user want. First of all, an executable file must have +x attribute for the current user, after that, if the user want to execute the file, a shell must be used. Typing "./file" on a shell command will execute the file using the default system shell.

Comment: I'd suggest an edit myself, but it's less than 6 characters but … threat != treat ;). It's a nice typo in the given context though :)

Comment: If you run xclock by clicking a desktop icon - is a shell involved?

Comment: For windows it is not **just** the extension. The OS also checks the first two bytes for the magic number 4D 5A. In ASCII this woul be MZ, the initials of Mark Zbikowski. He is the engineer that initially came up with the exe format for MS-DOS.

Comment: but in windows also there are .bat files .com files etc right...

Comment: .bat, .com, .vbs and .ps1 are script-oriented files. They are recognized by it's extension to run over the related program. (.bat and .com run on cmd; .vbs run on CScript; and .ps1 run over PowerShell interpreter).

Comment: @EBGreen I didn't know about that... Good to know.

Comment: Reference: http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

Comment: Also, be aware that VBScript and Powershell scripts are not **required** to have any specific extension in windows. You can explicitly call the interpreter and hand it any text file with any extension. There is probably a way to do this with a bat file as well, but I'm too lazy to figure it out.

Comment: @Diogo  so what happens in case of viruses in windows... they might come even with a jpeg or bmp or whatever format appearing to be a data file, but still execute by itself ..

Comment: A virus on jpg or bmp comes "embedded" on a picture or even is just an exe file with the extension changed. The virus will use some Windows [exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)) to run and then contaminate your machine.

Comment: "will execute the file using the default system shell" is wrong.  The command is interpreted by whatever shell you are typing it into.  The shell executes the program.  If the program is a script, then the kernel executes whatever interpreter the script specifies on its first line.  There is no default shell anywhere.

Comment: Do you have any reference? Linux always have a shell, " kernel executes whatever interpreter the script specifies on its first line". It means it will run the default shell. What maybe you are talking about is that there is no default shell for linux, all distributions are free to choose one option from the shell list. [Reference.](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Which_shell_is_used_by_Linux_as_the_default_command_interpreter)